# What's the .NET equivalent of a COM LocalServer?

Tags: .net, com, equivalent, localserver

In VB6, it was a simple matter to write applications that served up COM classes, the application would run as a system-wide singleton and would be able to serve COM classes to multiple processes. I believe this is called a COM LocalServer.

What's the equivalent in .NET? How can I make a single executable that handles requests from multiple applications or processes?

Answer (score 6):

The nearest equivalent would be [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(VS.90).aspx) (Windows Communication Foundation)

[Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

[Learn The ABCs Of Programming Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163647.aspx)

[Instance Management Techniques For Developing WCF Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx)

> The singleton service is the ultimate
>   shareable service. When a service is
>   configured as a singleton, all clients
>   get connected to the same single
>   well-known instance independently of
>   each other, regardless of which
>   endpoint of the service they connect
>   to. The singleton service lives
>   forever, and is only disposed of once
>   the host shuts down. The singleton is
>   created exactly once when the host is
>   created.

Comment: With COM servers they could be auto-launched by using the registered name. Is that possible with WCF? Can you point me to how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I did it but I think you just set the ObjectPooling attribute to 1?

[COM and .NET Component Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/comdotnetsvs/chapter/ch10.html)